# Add Rotate Hover a menu in CSS

Tags: css, menu, rotation, hover

I'm using css rotate on hover of a menu but I have a problem.

What I'm trying to achieve is the following.

when user hover over an image "+" it rotates 45° while the menu appears below.
Actually the image "+" keeps reseting to original position and the menu disappear.

I can't manage to display the menu and the image "+" rotated of 45°.

Here is the Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4Ts7n/7/

Your recommandations would be very welcome, thanks.

HTML

```
<header class="clearfix">
<nav>
<div class="cross"><img src="http://www.acielouvert.net/dm/images/nav_plus.png" width="221" height="221" /></div>
<ul>
<li>PROJET</li>
<li>PRESSE</li>
<li>EXHIBITION</li>
<li>CONTACT</li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

CSS

```
body {
background-color: #000;
}

nav ul {
list-style: none;
color: #fff;
font-size: 3.5rem;
text-align: center;
line-height: 3.5rem;
float: left;
opacity: 0;

-webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;

-webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
-moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
-o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
transition-duration: 0.8s;

-webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
-moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
-o-transition-property: -o-transform;
overflow:hidden;
}

nav :hover {
filter: alpha(opacity=1);
opacity: 1;
}

nav li {
color: #fff;
}

.cross {
margin: 55px 0 0 100px;
position: fixed;
text-align: left;

-webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
-moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
-o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
transition-duration: 0.8s;

-webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
-moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
-o-transition-property: -o-transform;
overflow:hidden;
}

.cross:hover {
-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
-o-transform:rotate(45deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the hover to `nav:hover .cross` rather than `.cross:hover`

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/4Ts7n/11/)

if you do the same with your ul it will stop the flickering effect:

```
nav:hover ul {
    filter: alpha(opacity=1);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/4Ts7n/12/)

Comment: No problems, glad I could help

Comment: It works fine that way, but user cannot click the link of the menu. Any idea why ?

Comment: Your cross is positioned fixed - try adding a z-index of -1 to it, I would position it absolutely to the nav too instead of fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/4Ts7n/13/